# Switch focus on next edittext after maxlength with doOntextListener with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext, focus

I'd like to set Focus on next EditText after Max char length reached.

I've got three EditTexts and a button. I'm getting a date as numbers, DD MM YYYY. I'd like to input two chars in `EditText1` and it should automatically move Focus to the second `EditText2`. Then once again I want it to set focus on the third `EditText3` which is year so it has four chars. After the user has input four chars the focus should be set on the button.

```
     override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(layout.activity_main)


        EditText1.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
            if(count == 2) {
                month.requestFocus()
            }
        }
        EditText2.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
            if(count == 2) {
                year.requestFocus()
            }
```

Comment: what is your problem exactly? Explain more, please.

Comment: I've got three EditTexts and button, I'm getting date as numbers, DD MM YYYY. I'd like to input two chars in EditText1 and it should automatilciy get Focus on second EditText2, then once again set focus on third EditText3 witch is year so it got four chars, after input four chars on it it have to set Focus on button